# jQuery JSON file not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to load a .json file present in my local project workspace using jQuery and I get the error - "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

```
<html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>TEST</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $.getJSON('phones.json',function(data){
                console.log('It Worked!')
            });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>

    <!-- end snippet -->

      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>TEST</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $.getJSON('phones.json',function(data){
                console.log('It Worked!')
            });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a web server and serve this page via http. That will eliminate the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This can be Googled. Chrome security is not allowing you to do local AJAX calls to your local directory. If the file will always be in your local file directory, include it with your `<script src="phones.json"></script>`. Note, this will cause the json variable to be global.

Alternatively, you can run your page on a local server to continue programming locally. This, too, can be googled on how to do this.